# Передать переменную

Tags: php, jquery

Есть таблица в БД, куда попадают покупки пользователей, мне нужно эти покупки по клику на кнопку скачивать в таблицу csv, реализовал это  помощью PHP. Но проблема в том, что он скачивает сразу все покупки, по всем торговым парам, а мне нужно, чтоб качалась информация только по парам, выбранным в селекторе, но скрипт селектора написан на jquery, и я не знаю как передать значения из скрипта jquery в php
Вот код пхп:

```
if(isset( $_POST['btnexp'] ) )
    {
$check = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `trade_history`  where $sesion_id=ID_prod");
    $results = array();

    while ($row = $check->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $results[] = $row['Val'] . ',' . $row['Prod'];
    }

    $content = join($results, "\n"); 
    $result->free();

    header("Content-Type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=myfilename.csv");
    echo $content;
die();
    }
```

Кусок из файла с селектором:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="btnexp" value="Load to file" />
</form>
```

Код селектора:

```
<select id="1" class="support__selector">
                                    <option value="BTC" selected>BTC</option>
                                    <option value="ETH">ETH</option>
                                    <option value="VRTM">VRTM</option>
                                    <option value="LTC">LTC</option>
                                    <option value="BCH">BCH</option>
                                    <option value="DASH">DASH</option>
                                    <option value="ZEC">ZEC</option>
                                    <option value="ETC">ETC</option>
                                    <option value="XMR">XMR</option>
                                </select>
```

Comment: Из `jquery` в `php` - используя `ajax`. По кнопке вызвать Ваш php код, которому передадутся данные селектора, и там уже их обработать в запросе к БД.

Comment: Дайте распечатку $_POST['btnexp']

Comment: @doox911 выдает тайтл кнопки

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов Можете посмотреть код?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша форма. Тегу select даем атрибут `name`, чтобы обратиться к нему потом.

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="btnexp" value="Load to file" />
    <select id="1" name="support1" class="support__selector">
        <option value="BTC" selected>BTC</option>
        <option value="ETH">ETH</option>
        <option value="ETC">ETC</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Ваш php:

```
if(isset($_POST['btnexp'])){
    // Получаем данные из селектора:
    $formSelector1 =  $_POST['support1'];

    // ...  остальной ваш код.
}
```

Comment: Попробовал вариант с гетом, все равно выдает  Undefined index: val in order_to file.php

Comment: @Ayurpwnz Надо бы ваш php файл посмотреть, можете обновить вопрос, покажите актуальный php код, какой он сейчас.

Comment: обновил вопрос, первый кусок это файл ordertofile

Comment: @Ayurpwnz Вы знаете, честно говоря, такая у вас мешанина, что ответить кратко не представляется возможным. Данные отправляются либо POST, либо GET, вы сейчас их одновременно пытаетесь использовать... Вы должны уловить суть производимых действий. Похоже, Вы отправляете форму, данные из которой попадают в массив $_POST. jquery скрипт селектора ни причем, он работает с формой до отправки. Верните весь старый код: все данные у вас были, по идее, вам просто нужно их найти в массиве $_POST и правильно использовать в sql-запросе.

Comment: обновил вопрос, этот код вы имели ввиду?

Comment: @Ayurpwnz да, все верно. В форме, получается, только кнопка одна? Приложите еще сам этот селектор, что хоть он делает, вообще непонятно, честно говоря...

Comment: добавил код одного селектора, 2ой аналогичный, только 1 кнопка в форме

Comment: Я так понимаю, весь этот код не ваш... Я бы мог подсказать что-то, но тут не знаешь, с чего начать. Если Вы понимаете, как работает отправка формы методом POST, тогда объяснять ничего не нужно было бы. Засуньте селект в форму и получайте данные - я бы сделал так. Если нет: чтобы вам помочь, мне нужно всю страницу переписать, получается... Это работа для фрилансера все-таки...

Comment: вы не могли бы показать как получить данные, если селектор расположен в форме?

Comment: и насчет кода вы не правы, он  мой, я просто не знаю как реализовать данную задачу.

Comment: обновил ответ, по идее так должно работать.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в sql запросе.

```
$check = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `trade_history`  where $sesion_id=ID_prod"); // Ошибочный

$check = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `trade_history` where ID_prod = " . $sesion_id); // Правильный
```

И сортировка  должна быть в самой таблице, то есть каждая строка должна соответствовать селектору.